# Django advanced query - objects of a Foriegnkey?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django models where I have this :

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    FirstName =       models.CharField(max_length=264)
    LastName =        models.CharField(max_length=264)
    Address =         models.TextField(blank=True)
    Telephone_no =    models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    user =            models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='patients')

class UploadedImages(models.Model):
    patient =           models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images')
    original =          models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_extension],verbose_name = 'Image')
    enhanced =          models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path, blank=True)
    segmented =         models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path, blank=True)

class Processed(models.Model):
    uploaded_image = models.ForeignKey(UploadedImages,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='processed')
    pre_analysed = models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path, blank=True)
    analysedimage = models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path, blank=True)
```

so I want to make queries based on the current user which is `user = request.user` this is possible in the patient model case as I can make `Patient.objects.filter(user=user)`

but i can't make it the other 2 models 
is there any idea how I can do this?
I didn't add the user FK as I thought I wouldn't need it but now I do?
do i need to add it ? can I make a query without adding the field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query across relationships, Django [has explicit syntax for that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).  For example, to get all the `UploadedImage` objects for a specific user, use `UploadedImage.objects.filter(patient__user=user)`.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help it was really handfull, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Patient.objects.filter(user=user)` returns a queryset, to get patient by user, **assuming one Patient has only one user**:

```
patient = Patient.objects.filter(user=user).first()
```

then you can do:

```
uploaded_images = patients.images.all()

for image in uploaded_images:
    processed = image.processed.all()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I used @RishiG's answer as it was more percise but i really appreciate your help.